# fstream operation sets failbit for ios::out mode

Tags: c++, ios, fstream

For the following simple test code in a class constructor:

```
//test_code.hpp
#ifndef TST_CDE_H
#define TST_CDE_H
#include<numeric>
#include<random>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<fstream>
using std::ios;
using std::ofstream;
using std::vector;
using std::iota;
using std::random_device;
using std::mt19937;
using std::shuffle;

#define FILENAME "DB_file.txt"
#define MAX_ELEMS 1000

class xRan{
public:
xRan();
private:
random_device rd;
};//end of class declaration 
#endif

//test_code.cpp
#include "test_code.hpp"

xRan::xRan(){
vector<int>v(MAX_ELEMS);
mt19937 g(rd());
auto mode = ios::out | ios::app | ios::trunc;
ofstream fs(FILENAME,mode);
if(fs.good()){
iota(v.begin(),v.end(),1);
shuffle(v.begin(),v.end(),g);
std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(fs, " "));
fs.close();
}
}//end of constructor defintion

//test_main.cpp
#include "test_code.hpp"

int main(){
xRan rand_obj;
return 0;
}//end of main()
```

the fstream operation to open a text file in output mode and write to it, sets the ios::failbit on the fstream.

```
Debugging using gdb gives the following steps:
(gdb) n
6   auto mode = ios::out | ios::app | ios::trunc;
(gdb) n
7   ofstream fs(FILENAME,mode);
(gdb) n
1219    {
(gdb) n
336     ios_base() {// purposefully does no initialization
(gdb) n
648     basic_ios() {// purposefully does no initialization
(gdb) n
1219    {
(gdb) n
1218        : basic_ostream<char_type, traits_type>(&__sb_)
(gdb) n
165     { this->init(__sb); }
(gdb) n
685     ios_base::init(__sb);
(gdb) n
686     __tie_ = 0;
(gdb) n
687     __fill_ = traits_type::eof();
(gdb) n
1219    {
(gdb) n
1177        explicit basic_ofstream(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::out);
(gdb) n
1220        if (__sb_.open(__s, __mode | ios_base::out) == 0)
(gdb) n
1221            this->setstate(ios_base::failbit);
(gdb) n
```

Any idea based on the code why the attempt to open a text file in output mode sets the ios::failbit on the fstream?

Would really appreciate your suggestions.

TIA
Vin

Comment: `app | trunc` is [not a valid combination](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open). These two flags make no sense together.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks mate, can I use out | trunc instead?

Comment: I want to discard all the contents of the file present before writing to it

Comment: I trust you know how to follow links. Should you choose to follow the one I've provided, you would find a table exhaustively listing all valid combinations, with a short explanation for each.

Comment: @ Igor Thanks I overlooked the link in your previous post. Thank you very much for your prompt response.

Comment: I might also casually suggest indentation is quite a useful thing....